# setting a minimum allowed size for the panels of SplitterContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, autoresize, splitter

Greeting,
in C# WinForms:
I have a splitterContainer. and lets sat there is Docked to Fill TableLayout in SplitterContainer.Panel1 
now when I move the Splitter bar, it can cover the area of each of its panels. so it can even hide one of its panels when we move the splitter bar. But I do not want it! I want to have a limit for that. the minimum size I want to always be available for the panels of the SplitteRContainer is the  size that is necessary for the contents that are already inside each panel of it. I do not want to be able to hide one panel and its contents by moving the splitter bar, so when it gets to that point I want it to stop moving and resizing the panels.
Can you please help me on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`Panel1MinSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1minsize.aspx).

Comment: Ok
splitContainer1.Panel1MinSize = ??? ;
I mean what to write on the right side of the equation?
Panel1 has a TableLayout which is docked to Fill

Comment: Hmm, ok, maybe I can set it to the width of the largest control inside the tableLayout panel?
I will try it now

Comment: From the link provided:

"An Int32 representing the minimum distance in pixels of the splitter from the left or top edge of Panel1."

Comment: the example in the link is using hard coded values. is there a good idea how not to use hard coded values?

Comment: I don't think there's any simple way to get the minimum size of your `TableLayoutPanel`.  You could loop through all of the columns and add the sizes of the widest controls in each column.

Comment: a question for you Sir: on what EVENT of the splitterContainer?   "Move" event is not firing

Comment: ok, thanks for the property name.  I also found the correct event for it :

        private void splitContainer1_SplitterMoved(object sender, SplitterEventArgs e)
        {
            splitContainer1.Panel1MinSize = ctlDateRangeAccept.Width;

Comment: @BDotA: no, set it in the form constructor.  SplitterMoved is too late.